# Im getting this error "TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'handleShow' of 'object null' as it is null." Kindly Help me with this

Tags: reactjs, compiler-errors, modal-dialog, mern, ref

TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'handleShow' of 'object null' as it is null.This error comes everytime but when i refresh everything works properly for some time i tried removing handle show and added replaced it with obj and inside i added obj&&obj.handleshow then this.showModal function doesnot exist this error comes

```
Dashboard.js:

    SearchModalRef = ({handleShow}) => {
            this.showModal = handleShow;
        }
        
        onClick = () => {
            this.showModal();
        }
    render(){
    return(
    <SearchModal  ref={this.SearchModalRef} ></SearchModal>
                            <button type="button" onClick={this.onClick}>
                            Search
                            </button>
    }
    )
SearchModal.js:-

    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { SearchUser } from '../services/SearchService';
    import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/Modal'
    
    class SearchModal extends Component {
      constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            show: false,
            search: '',
            userdetails:[]
        }
    
        this.handleShow = this.handleShow.bind(this);
        this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this);
        this.onTextboxChangeSearch = this.onTextboxChangeSearch.bind(this);
    }
    
    handleShow() {
        this.setState({ show: true })
    }
    handleClose(){
        this.setState({ show: false,search:'' })
    }
    
    onTextboxChangeSearch(event) {
      const { value } = event.target;
      this.setState({
        search: value // <-- (1) update state
      });
    }
    
    
    SearchForUser = async () => { // <-- (3) refactored search function
      const { search, userdetails } = this.state;
      const data = { username: search };
    
      const  user  = await SearchUser(data);
      this.setState({ userdetails: user.user });
    }
    
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
      if (prevState.search !== this.state.search) {
        this.SearchForUser(); // <-- (2) search state updated, do search for user
      }
    }
    
    
    render() {
        let {search,userdetails}= this.state;
        return (
           <div>
              <Modal show={this.state.show} onHide={this.handleClose} 
              dialogClassName="modal-90w"
              aria-labelledby="example-custom-modal-styling-title"
               >
                 <Modal.Header closeButton>
                   <Modal.Title>
                     <input 
                      type="text" 
                      placeholder="Search.."
                      value={search}
                      onChange={this.onTextboxChangeSearch}
                     ></input>
                   </Modal.Title>
                 </Modal.Header>
                 <Modal.Body>
                   <h3>Users</h3>
                   <div>
                    <ul className="collection">
                      {userdetails.map((element,i) => {
                        return(
                          <li key={i}>{element.username}</li>
                        );
                      })}
                    </ul>
                   </div>
                 </Modal.Body>
              </Modal>
            </div>
        )
      }
    }
    export default SearchModal;
```

Comment: `ref={this.SearchModalRef}` will pass itself into your `SearchModalRef`. So destructuring it with `{handleShow}` makes zero sense.

Comment: even when i did this its givinfg error
  24 |    SearchModalRef = (handleShow) => {
> 25 |        this.showModal = handleShow;
     | ^  26 |    }
  27 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this way (Updated)

```
SearchModalRef = (obj) => { 
   this.showModal = obj && obj.handleShow 
}
```

Comment: Since you bothered to post an answer. Could take the time to also elaborate as to why his code throws that error?

Comment: TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'handleShow' of 'object null' as it is null.
Dashboard.SearchModalRef
C:/pratik web/ping/frontend/src/components/Dashboard.js:25
  22 |    }
  23 | 
  24 |    SearchModalRef = (handleShow) => {
> 25 |        this.showModal = handleShow;
     | ^  26 |    }
  27 |    
  28 |    onClick = () => {

Comment: its working now i tried this too but i didnt destructed it so it was giving me error when i tried thanks for this